# Kotlin + Exoplayer - icecast url

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I am trying to learn Exoplayer but can seem to find a simple how-to set up a exoplayer to play icecast streams.

I have followed all the tuts I can find but just can't seem to get it to work.

I know how to do it in MediaPlayer - but I have noticed a few issues like I can't stop the player by triggering `mp.stop()` So I thought I would move to Exoplayer but that is even harder.

MediaPlayer code

```
    val url = "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream" // your URL here
            val mp = MediaPlayer()
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            mp.setDataSource(url)
            mp.prepare() // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
    
            mp.start()
```

ExoPlayer Code

```
    private lateinit var simpleExoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer

    private val url = "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream"
val uri = Uri.parse(url)
                        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(url)
                        simpleExoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
```

But that does not work I get this error

> Type mismatch: inferred type is String but MediaSource was expected